# I try to connect MySQL with nodejs but Error:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, node.js

I try to connect MySQL with nodejs but Error:Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

```
const mysql = require("mysql2")

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host:"127.0.0.1",
    port:"3306",
    user:"root",
    password:"123456",
    database:"my_db_01"
})

db.connect((err,conn)=>{
    if(err) {
        console.log('MySQL connection error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
})
```

But my command line and MySQL workbench can connect mysql successfully.Why is that?

I think it might be my dependency verion,so I change that but useless.

Comment: `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'` Can you try to run this in your mysql workbench? Or change the host to `localhost` in the connection envs

Comment: You'd better use `connectionPools` https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#:~:text=%7D%0A)%3B-,Using%20connection%20pools,-Connection%20pools%20help

Comment: I have already done that but still the same that

Comment: Did you try to alter user?

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, 127.0.0.1 is different from localhost. Judging from the error message provided, the reasons for this problem are as follows:
1.127.0.0.1 mapping of hosts file
2.skip_name_resolve parameter
You can check it and it will solve the problem

Comment: But no matter what I write 127.0.0.1 or localhost always like this

Comment: @YuanJ check select user,host from mysql.user;    show variables like "%skip%";

Comment: adfsfjslkdfjsldkfjlasjfljsdflkjsdlfkjdslfjsldkfjklasjflkdsa flkajsdflkjdsalkf aldskfj lsdka lkasjdf lkasdjf lkasdjf ldksfjlskdjflsdfjadfsfjslkdfjsldkfjlasjfljsdflkjsdlfkjdslfjsldkfjklasjflkdsa flkajsdflkjdsalkf aldskfj lsdka lkasjdf lkasdjf lkasdjf ldksfjlskdjflsdfjadfsfjslkdfjsldkfjlasjfljsdflkjsdlfkjdslfjsldkfjklasjflkdsa flkajsdflkjdsalkf aldskfj lsdka lkasjdf lkasdjf lkasdjf ldksfjlskdjflsdfjadfsfjslkdfjsldkfjlasjfljsdflkjsdlfkjdslfjsldkfjklasjflkdsa flkajsdflkjdsalkf aldskfj lsdka lkasjdf lkasdjf lkasdjf ldksfjlskdjflsdfj